# Error: 'sparkR.session' is not an exported object from 'namespace:SparkR'

Tags: sparkr

I'm trying to figure out a Spark error, but no result so far and i'm reaching you for any kind of clue.
When I'm calling spark I've got:

```
Error: 'sparkR.session' is not an exported object from 'namespace:SparkR'
```

And i've followed another thread around here in which I found something like:

```
SparkR:::sparkR.session
```

But no result and I don't understand very much this.

Answer (score 1):

Two colons, not 3....`SparkR::sparkR.session()`